# Bash - find files older than X minutes and move them

Tags: linux, bash

I need to create a bash script and put in CRON - on linux.
I need to loop through or just find all files in directory DIR_A and if files are older than, for example, 10 minutes, move them to directory DIR_B.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I am sure a little googling lets you find a looot of similar questions to start from. Do it and share it with us, then let us know what is the problem you are facing

Comment: Not a perfect duplicate but simply a case of replacing `rm` with `mv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else needs it:

```
find DIR_A -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin +10 -exec mv "{}" DIR_B/ \
```

Comment: I would suggest using `-mmin -10` instead of `-mtime`, since he/she asked for minutes.